# Does prestige reset weapon prestige?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-3

In Call of Duty, Black Ops 3, does prestiging your main player rank reset each weapon prestige as well?

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark it as accepted for possible future viewers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Black Ops 2 is anything to go by, when activating prestige, everything will get reset with the exception of weapon levels and camo's.

It may also be worth noting that Specialists, Weapons, Lethal, Tactical, Perk 1, Perk 2, Perk 3, Wildcards, and Scorestreaks are all permenantly unlockable using the token.

This is also some information I found regarding Prestige:

[image]